# Angularjs filter on nested property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of the following json object:

```
 { 
    fooBar:{ 
        Id: 2
        Foo:  { 
                Id: 4
                IsNew: false
              } 
         Bar: { 
                Id: 1
                IsNew: false
              }
           }
  }
```

and I want to filter on the `fooBar.Foo.Id`, so based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20579621/1005609) I was expecting the following to work:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="fooBar in fooBars | filter:{Foo:{Id : 4}}:true">
```

But this does not return me anything.

I can do the following however to filter on fooBar.Id and that works fine:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="fooBar in fooBars | filter:{Id : 2}:true">
```

Should I be writing custom filters for this kind of one level down child property matching? Or is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post a plunker or a fiddle? and replicate the problem?

Comment: Did you see the updated JS Bin on your referred question? [Look at this filter](http://jsbin.com/ObIqUyix/1/edit). They ended up with another solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583496/1005609), I solved the problem by creating a custom filter:

```
app.filter('fooBarFilter', [function () {
 return function (foobars, fooId) {
     var result = {};

     angular.forEach(foobars, function (foobar, key) {
         if (foobar.foo.Id === fooId) {
             result[key] = foobar;
         }
     });
     return result;
 };
}]);
```

and used it to filter the collection in the HTML:

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="(key, fooBar) in fooBars | fooBarFilter : 4">
```